# What is the meaning of this note in the spec?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

What is the meaning of this? This is regarding the `Array.prototype.concat` method, but it's stated throughout the spec, again and again, for a series of methods.

> The concat function is intentionally generic; it does not require that
>   its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to
>   other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the concat
>   function can be applied successfully to a host object is
>   implementation-dependent.

Can you explain this in simple wording, perhaps providing an example as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you can apply the method to an array-like object even if it's not an `Array`. These include `NodeList`s and the `arguments` object.

I sometimes use this feature to turn the `arguments` object into an array: `[].slice.call(arguments)` returns the argument list as an `Array` object, giving me native access to all the array methods.

You can read about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Generic_methods).